# Passing variables from page to content script in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, content-security-policy

I'm working on a chrome extension that will require me to grab the subtitle file from a youtube video, and then do some processing. I have all of the logic set up to do that, but the link to the subtitles is stored in a global variable on the page (ytInitialPlayerResponse), unaccessible from the context of my content script.

So, I simply need to inject a window.postMessage call into the youtube page, and pass the variable to my content script (as per the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts#host-page-communication)).

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript'
let code = `
    let sendBaseUrl = () => {
        window.postMessage({type : "FROM_PAGE", text : "Hello from the webpage!"}, "*");
    }
`
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code))
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

However, I'm prevented from doing so due to the content security policy in place against executing inline scripts.

The subtitles will need to be fetched every time a video is loaded, and I haven't seen a programmatic way of retrieving the url to the subtitle file other than through this variable. Youtube does have a similar functionality with their API, but as far as I'm aware, requests require you to be authenticated as the publisher of the video.

I'm not quite sure what to do at this stage. I obviously have no control over the content security policy, and this is my first time writing a chrome extension, so I haven't come across this situation before.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the duplicate, I really tried to search for an answer, but all I could find were situations where the extension owner controlled both the page context and content script.

I found a beautiful explanation of all the possible ways you can go about solving this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/13311415), thanks to Rob W.

In short, I created another js file purely to hold the script I wanted to inject.

get_subs.js

```
let sendBaseUrl = () => {
        let baseUrl = ytInitialPlayerResponse.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer.captionTracks.find(x => x.languageCode.indexOf("ja") === 0)?.baseUrl
        window.postMessage({type : "YOMI_GET_SUBS", subUrl : baseUrl}, "*");
}

sendBaseUrl()
```

and added the following entry to my manifest.json, to allow it to be accessed by other pages
manifest.json

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["scripts/get_subs.js"],
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"]
    }],
```

finally, inject the script into the page
content.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('scripts/get_subs.js');
s.onload = function() { this.remove(); };
// see also "Dynamic values in the injected code" section in this answer
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```